# Can't activate Jupyter kernel in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

1. I work in Anaconda.
2. I work in windows 10.
3. I created a new environment - python 3.7 for Jupyter.
4. I installed (using the navigator) the Jupyter package in the package when it said:

> Jupyter metapapackage. Install all the Jupyter components in one go.

5. I activated the Jupyter from Anaconda navigator (using this environment).
6. I opened a new python 3 notebook. It said Kernel Error in the notebook page in the top left.
7. I took the google Machine Learning course. Thus the ports 8888 and 8889 where occupied. So I changed in the Jupyter Config the port to be 8887.
   Attached the Jupyter Config file and the Jupyter kernel log

[Config file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P-X5J0tjAQj5goEvjVvYqVarrERIcK8O/view?usp=sharing)
 (The only changes are the port and log setting)

[Kernel Log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13Ku6Z_2Va5DCwEwl5RxPOp_mWHO3X7YY/view?usp=sharing)

The following is a screen shot of the error. It looks like it is looking for a file holds the information for the startup. Do you know which file it is and where it should be put?

As I told you I have a working installation on another computer so if I will know which file it is I can bring it.
[image: A screen shot which contains the error]

Comment: Could you add pictures? I'm not following your error log.

Comment: Pictures of what? The notebook page says Kernel error. Is there another place to view the error?. If you will tell me what are your assumption or speculations perhaps I can give you more data. As I said I am a beginner in Jupiter.

Comment: Usually, the anaconda prompt has useful errors.

Comment: I activated it from the anaconda navigator. Do you know the command for activating Jupiter from the command prompt?

Comment: Jyupter notebook

Comment: Please paste your error as text instead of using a screenshot.